# spring boot 1.2.3.RELEASE - @SpringBootApplication does not do EnableWebMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, resteasy

After wasting half a day on this I found that @SpringBootApplication doesn't enable spring-webmvc as documented. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ says that as long as spring-webmvc is on classpath spring boots loads it. I found it otherwise abd had to addd @Enablewebmvc to enable spring dispatcherservlet and in turns resteasy controller. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies did you include?

Comment: Like @IanRoberts said, if you look at the 'Build with Maven' section from the guide, you can see the example brings in the `spring-boot-starter-web` starter pom. With that you should not have to use `@EnableWebMvc` as the web starter enables auto configuration of `spring-webmvc` from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.provides).